# How to build a React app despite having errors in CSS

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app where I am trying to build it now. It has a third party CSS file which it is erroring out at:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/css/style2.css
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 61
```

The CSS file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Jv0mfg2r_AMiOc06N9BknJhtxV9swfA/view?usp=sharing), although I don't expect anyone to go through that massive file.

My questions are:

1. Why does this work normally but fails at build?
2. How can I move on from this, despite there being errors?

Thanks

Comment: Many of us can't see that file. Better to post the offending lines as code here.

Comment: What does "work normally" mean? Why would you want to ignore errors?

Comment: The file could change, or not be available in the future. In other words, your question (and possible answers) wouldn't help anyone. It's usually expected that debugging questions like this have the offending code within the question body.

Comment: First, you can use this CSS validator http://www.css-validator.org.
Second, for parsing errors you need to set up appropriate CSS loaders

Comment: It's a 17k line CSS file. @chazsolo - I am, of course, not gonna paste that here. Furthermore file isn't mine - as in I had a template which I just used.

Comment: @isherwood - as in it works when you use the file on the site. There aren't any errors or weird behaviour. The point being - this is not my file, I bought it from a theme maker site and have no problems using it. I just am having issues building it. It's a 17k lines file so I don't think it's realistic for me to be editing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being an issue as the .css files were being imported under index.js.

To workaround this problem, I just added the CSS files as stylesheets under index.html and it worked.